# How to limit the aggregation of dates difference in the case of there were overlaps between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012, aggregate

How to limit the aggregation of dates difference in the case of there were overlaps between them.

If i have a table **Mission** like this :

```
   emp_num   from_date                 to_date
   1336       2017-02-07 00:00:00.000   2017-02-08 00:00:00.000
   1336       2017-02-15 00:00:00.000   2017-02-16 00:00:00.000
   1336       2017-02-21 00:00:00.000   2017-02-23 00:00:00.000
   1336       2017-02-26 00:00:00.000   2017-02-26 00:00:00.000
   1336       2017-02-28 00:00:00.000   2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
```

---

I want to get the summation of (to_date - from_date) in a specific month of year.

in this example **the result of the total mission days in 2-2017** should equal to  **9 days**.

---

I did the following query but i get `10` days instead of `9` days because of the overlapping with the next month !

```
SELECT b.emp_num,b.NAME AS FullName ,c.DEPTNAME AS DeptName,d.camp_name AS CampName
,SUM(DATEDIFF(day,a.from_date ,a.to_date)+1) AS Mission_SUM
FROM Mission a INNER JOIN Employee b
ON a.emp_num = b.emp_num
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT c
ON b.dep_code = c.dep_code
INNER JOIN Branch d
ON d.camp_code = b.camp_code
where ((Year(from_date) =2017 AND Month(from_date)=2) OR (Year(to_date) =2017 AND Month(to_date)=2))
and mission_type = 1
GROUP BY b.emp_num,b.NAME,c.DEPTNAME,d.camp_name
ORDER BY d.camp_name,c.DEPTNAME,b.NAME
```

---

I want to get the total number of days in **2-2017** for employees ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query

```
DECLARE @FirstDate date = '2017-02-01'
DECLARE @EndDate date = EoMonth(@FirstDate)

SELECT b.emp_num,b.NAME AS FullName ,c.DEPTNAME AS DeptName,d.camp_name AS CampName
,SUM(DATEDIFF(day,
            IIF(a.from_date > @FirstDate, a.from_date, @FirstDate) ,
            IIF(a.to_date < @EndDate, a.to_date, @EndDate))+1) AS Mission_SUM
FROM Mission a INNER JOIN Employee b
ON a.emp_num = b.emp_num
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT c
ON b.dep_code = c.dep_code
INNER JOIN Branch d
ON d.camp_code = b.camp_code
where ((Year(from_date) =2017 AND Month(from_date)=2) OR (Year(to_date) =2017 AND Month(to_date)=2))
and mission_type = 1
GROUP BY b.emp_num,b.NAME,c.DEPTNAME,d.camp_name
ORDER BY d.camp_name,c.DEPTNAME,b.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

my be i didn't under Stand  You Well , but as i think You need to get the diffidence between to date , So I have Create A function to Calc this in Year month Day and it's return a table so you can choose what the value You Want

You can Update it to get the result You want OR You can ask me For Help To make You get the Correct Result :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDateDifferenceInYearsMonthsDays]
(
    @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS
 @DateDifference TABLE (
 YEAR INT,  MONTH INT, DAYS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT, @tmpFromDate DATETIME = @FromDate
    SET @Years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@FromDate) > MONTH(@ToDate)) OR (MONTH(@FromDate) = MONTH(@ToDate) AND DAY(@FromDate) > DAY(@ToDate)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
    SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(m, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate) - CASE WHEN DAY(@FromDate) > DAY(@ToDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFromDate)
    SET @Days =  DATEDIFF(d, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)


    INSERT INTO @DateDifference
    VALUES(@Years, @Months, @Days)

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of achieving this is like below. Hope it covers all the scenarios. Have considered only dates.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (FROMDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE)
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES('2017-02-07','2017-02-08')
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES('2017-02-15','2017-02-16')
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES('2017-02-21','2017-02-23')
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES('2017-02-26','2017-02-26')
INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES('2017-02-28','2017-03-01')

SELECT SUM(TOTALDAYS) TOTALDAYS
FROM (
        SELECT TOTALDAYS= 
                CASE WHEN MONTH(FROMDATE)=MONTH(ENDDATE) AND YEAR(FROMDATE)=YEAR(ENDDATE) THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(D,FROMDATE,ENDDATE))+COUNT(1) 
                    WHEN  MONTH(FROMDATE)!=MONTH(ENDDATE) THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(D,FROMDATE,EOMONTH(FROMDATE)))+1
                END
        FROM #TMP
        GROUP BY FROMDATE,ENDDATE 
    ) A

DROP TABLE #TMP
```